# key as variable when accessing javascript dictionary

Tags: javascript, variables, dictionary, key

i am trying to store css values for transformations of multiple divs in a dictionary
to access them when the div is clicked (the div id being the key of the dict).

my dictionary:

```
css_dict = {
    'keyA' : ['10px, 15px', '20px', '10px'],
    'keyB' : ['20px, 30px', '10px', '20px'],
    'keyA' : ['30px, 55px', '25px', '30px'],
}
```

i need to access it like this (variable instead of the key):

```
css_dict.var[0]
```

jsFiddle of what im trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/tKFka/25/

i cant figure out or find the right syntax for this to work...

Comment: Try `css_dict[var][0]`. http://jsfiddle.net/tKFka/28/

Comment: Is there any literal form? such as `$` in `var mykey="k", mydict={$mykey: 'value'}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `[]` instead of dot.

```
var var1 = 'keyA';
css_dict[var1][0];
```

Comment: thanks a lot... i am glad the answer is so simple and feel stupid for not finding out myself -.-

Comment: This is a common way and should be the accepted answer. But square bracket notation is an antipattern as it might introduce a security issue (leading to remote code execution).
Using the eslint-plugin `security/recommended` this would lead to an error here.

https://web.archive.org/web/20150430062816/https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2015/01/15/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation